# Variable causes NullReferenceException even though it's set

Tags: c#, .net, events, nullreferenceexception

Maybe I'm doing something really wrong, but somehow this code always crashes with a NullReferenceException:

```
public class IncomingMessageEventData : EventArgs
{
    public IncomingMessageEventData(SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData _msg, List<string> _toreturn)
    {
        msg = _msg;
        ToReturn = _toreturn;
    }
    public SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData msg { get; set; }
    public List<string> ToReturn { get; set; }
}
public delegate void IncomingMessageHook(IncomingMessageEventData Args);
public event IncomingMessageHook InComingMessage;
public string NewMessage(string[] _message, System.Net.IPEndPoint RemoteIP)
{
    if (InComingMessage != null)
    {
        IncomingMessageEventData data = new IncomingMessageEventData(new SpecialClasses.IncomingMessageData(_message, RemoteIP), new List<string>());
        string ToReturn = "";
        InComingMessage(data);
        foreach (var item in data.ToReturn)
        {
if (item.Length > 0)
    ToReturn = item;
        }
        return ToReturn;
    }
    else return null;
}
```

There's 2 methods hooking to the event simultaneously, can that be the cause? If so, how do I avoid it? Or is passing a ref List just not the way to get values from a hooked method?

Thanks!

Edit: updated the code. Which works now! ... I think I know what I did wrong though.

See, the program this is part of uses plugins which it loads through Reflection, And there might have been the slightest possibility that I forgot to copy the updated plugin dll to the plugin directory before debugging. .. . hehe. ^^;
Sorry! But at least my code uses best practices now ;P So many thanks for that one and I'll mark it as answer!

Comment: can you provide the code for the `InComingMessage` method?

Comment: Are you sure _ToReturn is not null? Are you sure you have the correct location of the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: If `_ToReturn` is not null i assume that it actually crashes at `if (item.Length > 0)` because at least one of you strings is null.

Comment: It's nothing special, it just adds ToReturn either "something" or just leaves it as it is. Also I can even debug ToReturn in visual studio, It's obviously not null..

Comment: That parameter should not be `ref`.  Please show us the method in the delegate.

Comment: What line throws the exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: Here, this is a screenshot taken from Visual Studio: http://cedzscreen.fennecweb.net/Image-27-12-2011_201-39-48.png . And fine, I'll add the methods, like I said, they're pretty much empty because this is a testing/debug stage to find out what's wrong

Comment: After the exception is displayed in that dialog, go to the Immediate window and type `$exception.ToString()` to see the full exception details.

Comment: Thanks all, and sorry for being a tad slow, the exception is: $exception.ToString()
"System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.\r\n   at OnySteamInteraction.Augmentation.OnyEvents_InComingMessage(IncomingMessageData msg)\r\n   at OnyLib.BotStuff.BotEvents.NewMessage(String[] _message, IPEndPoint RemoteIP) in Main.cs:line 73"

Comment: The stacktrace is: http://cedzscreen.fennecweb.net/Image-27-12-2011_201-47-53.png And I'm sorry, I'm a selftaught coder and still a little rusty on the edges. Thanks all for helping out so far

Comment: Try disabling "Just My Code" to get more useful data in the stacks window: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx

Comment: Please show us the method you're calling in the delegate.

Comment: @SLaks I'll pastebin it, it's rather large to just put in here. Sorry for being slow about it, I'm about to update the post with the updated code I wrote..

Comment: So yea, As the updated post describes. Ups, my bad, But many thanks to all of you helping me improve the code though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.

Passing a `List<T>` as a ref parameter is not a good approach.  The `List<T>` can already be modified without involving `ref` / `out` just by using the standard `Add` / `Remove` methods already available on the type.

You are using a nonstandard form for event handlers.  It is more conventional to stick to `EventHandler<TEventArgs>` where `TEventArgs` is some class deriving from `EventArgs`. Data to be passed back and forth from the event handler should be handled by using properties or methods on your custom `EventArgs` class.

Your event handler logic is not thread-safe. You need to capture a local copy of the event handler to account for the case when someone unsubscribes right after you do the null check.  Here is the typical pattern:

```
// Capture the handler in a local
EventHandler<MyEventArgs> handler = this.MyEvent;
if (handler != null)
{
    // Invoke using the local copy
    handler(this, new MyEventArgs(/* ... */));
}
```

Comment: I'll try implement it that way. Removing 'ref' didn't change it though, I'm gonna implement the class now though.